# Observing any AJAX call (Prototype)

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, observer-pattern, dom-events

I want to set up an observer (using Prototype) which will be triggered when any AJAX call (to the server) is being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [global ajax responders](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Responders/) could solve your problem. But these will work only with ajax calls made by prototype I think.